# Enforcing type info on values of object arrays in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to enforce the __type attribute when serializing object arrays as JSON? For example, I have following array:

```cs
var data = new object[]
{
    "string value",
    new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"name", 1.23}
        }
};
```

When I serialize this using

```cs
var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(data);
```

I get following result

```
["string value",{"name":1.23}]
```

Deserializing using

```cs
var result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object[]>(json);
// result == new object[] {"string value", "{name:1.23}"}
```

leads to an array containing two strings. The second one is the JSON serialized dictionary representation.

Is there a way to enforce the __type attribute to allow ServiceStack to deserialize to the right type? The array can contain almost anything JSON serializable.

This is an internal API with ServiceStack on both sides. The possible types are not known at compile time.